What was the main method of interplanetary travel in the Blade Runner universe?
Are there any sources that are canonical to the movie version of Blade Runner (as opposed Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep) that discuss the main method of interplanetary space travel in the Blade Runner universe?
If so, what do these sources say?

There's barely any mention of space travel in the movie ... just references to 'off-world-colonies', and the famous 'attack ships ... off the shoulder of Orion' speech, and that Replicants are used to explore.  Given its not mentioned in the movie and you exclude the novel, what canonical sources would you accept?

I can't quote it myself but: "Niander Wallace's words about wishing to see mankind reach the stars heavily suggest that there is no interstellar travel yet." - suggests even less has been established in the sequel. At least in DADOES there is mention of colonies on Mars, and Rosen mentioning Rachael on the Salader 3 heading for Proxima. Movie-wise, Bryant mentions intergalactic run for Leon (loader) but thats the only reference. Reps on Calantha is shown in the anime, travel method not shown.

Also see  "How are the off-world colonies reached in Blade Runner?" - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/186119/140676

There are extensive comics and other media that are considered fully canon to the films. Space travel features regularly.

We can conclude that it is highly advanced and superluminal since they have reach distant stars such as those in Orion. PKD was not a hard scifi writer, not worried about plausibility of technologies mentioned.

@iandotkelly, the anime, comics and video games are canon to the movies. As is the movie novelization. I'm only excluding Do Androids Dream. Everything else canon is on the table.

That's a shame, before the comics, the internet, I always had an idea of the Gate as place, an intangible phenomenon, to wonder at in space, huge and spectacular, as if the folklore was right, but just not a door, or swinging gate. PKD wasn't a hard sci-fi writer in my mind, so between the movie and the book I just didn't want a 'door' - we already have stargates, jump-gates, what-have-you in other franchises. Before the deleted scenes, in Soldier (1998) I was glad it was still left ambiguous, as just 'a battle..'

In brief, the 'off-world' travel in the Blade Runner fictional universe is inconsistent, incomprehensible and leaves every question unanswered.
The very short answer is that in the two original films there's essentially no mention of how off-world travel is accomplished.

If we take the comics as canon, we see a star gate in Blade Runner 2019 #6. This appears to be a riff off of Hauer's speech where he mentions something called the "Tannhauser Gate". It has no obvious mechanism and we don't see it working. It merely exists.

Travel to the stargate is undertaken using some form of sublight engine. These have large and visible glowing stacks but no visible exhaust. It's not clear what fuel they're using or the energy source propelling them.

Shame, I rather enjoyed the Gate being ambiguous in my mind (before Soldiers deleted scene, and I had never read the comics..), that it was a place, or a place of reference. I rather enjoyed the idea of a battle playing out against the background of some enormous colorful phenomenon in deep space.. oh well...

Submitting as a partial, or not even as an answer, and also probably not answering this per se, but:
(thought I would put it in as I have not seen it mentioned elsewhere)

What was the main method of interplanetary travel in the Blade Runner universe?

Blade Runner 2049 explicitly shows an Off-World ship - only that there is no further information beyond that - there is no explanation for power source nor how it functions for example.
Concept artwork by Adam Baines for Blade Runner 2049:

Offworld Ship
Sketches for a ship seen overhead when leaving LA. I did some quick block out sketches in 3d Coat and then did some rough renders to mock up the shot.

These made it in to the movie, where you see it looming out over the landscape:

More detail from concept:

Interestingly, these vessels are not only interplanetary, they are capable of operating in the atmosphere...
Earlier concept examples:

His page can be found here: https://adamb.artstation.com/projects/x9NzE
Note:
Because of the design, many thought it was a link to the Alien universe or even the Sulaco itself, which obviously it was not:

And just to add, the 1998 movie Soldier penned by BR's David Peoples, with BR Easter Eggs added by the vfx artists and BR's Art Director David Snyder (replica Spinners), added ships that were either in battle at Tannhauser Gate (suggested) or some other battle in the Off World colonies (in the script as the Trinity Moons), and was considered as sharing its universe with BR (or sidequel):

(IIRC, the battle sequence is incomplete due to budget, and was referenced as a deleted battle at Tannhauser Gate). Having said all that, despite the connections I'm pretty sure most do not consider Soldier's shared universe as canon though.
even more off-topic, I found these of the Soldier interplanetary ships:


"They travel by spaceship, we actually see one" seems a perfectly fine answer to me!

I suppose I was umming and ahhing because I thought OP wanted 'hyperdrive!' or 'generational sub-light!', 'futuromangodrive!', and 'duriansmellodrive!' etc detailed explanations... :P

Oh sure, we have no idea how that thing actually stays up in the air instead of falling down and killing thousands. Probably it uses some of the same anti-gravity tech as the spinners.
